# Unable to run pytest command using .bat file but same command is ok in pytest terminal

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest

I'm using  this command in pytest terminal and it is running fine: pytest -v -s -m  "sanity or regression or functional"  --html=./Reports/report.html testCases/ --browser chrome --capture=tee-sys

But same command when I saved to .bat file and run as administrator it giving error as unable to import wedriver_manager.

Attaching both snapshots.

run.bat - NOT OK

[image]

pycharm terminal - ok
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to see code. However, a wild try you could give is to change `--capture=tee-sys` to `--capture=sys`, although, I do not think it has anything to do with the webdriver-manager.
Also, are you using a virtual environment or is it native?

Comment: Thanks for dropping an answer! In general, on stack overflow. Please keep responses that are asking a question to the post comments. Happy to have you here!